# Php: How to store a token and retrieve it for comparing?

Tags: php, cookies

Hi I am creating a token to compare against some record on the database to log a user in. I am using `token = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` to set this random string, but how its stored on the browser and database seem to be different. How do I compare these two strings?

Answer (score 0):

Set the value token first using a cookie way

```
$value = "23asdoq23ARDAsdadq2";

// cookie will expire when the browser close
setcookie("tokenCookie", $value);

// cookie will expire in 1 hour or set it to your needs
setcookie("tokenCookie", $value, time() + 3600);
```

or set the duration to 0, so that cookie duration will end only when users browser is close

```
setcookie("tokenCookie", $value, 0);
```

then retrieved the cookie and compare selected token value from the database with the cookie token.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['tokenCookie'])) {
    $tokenCookie = $_COOKIE['tokenCookie'];

    // Assume you already retrieved the token value from the database and stored it to a variable then you just need to compare it..

    if( $tokenCookie == $token_value_from_database ){
        echo true;
    }else{
        echo false;
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the $tokenCookie - $_COOKIE['tokenCookie'] do?